# Could most AC devices run off of DC rather than AC?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

To be clear - I have absolutely ZERO intention of ever doing this.  But when I learned what a rectifier does (flip the negative portion of the voltage into positive), it occurred to me that it ought to be able to accept DC as well (it would just have nothing to "rectify" beyond the polarity of the source voltage).

Is this correct?  If so, in what cases would it NOT work?

Comment: You could've powered a light bulb with DC if you reduced the voltage to correct the RMS to a value that the bulb can bear, and you could've powered a simple heater devices similarly - and that's basically all of possible "AC" devices (neither are true AC devices, mind me, as true AC-fed circuit (i.e. using coils & caps) simply wouldn't run on DC) you could could feed with DC.

Comment: @vaxquis:  The RMS voltage is equal to the DC voltage that would produce the same effective power: a 120 V light bulb will work equally well on 120 V RMS AC as on 120 V DC - no need to reduce orotherwise adjust voltages.

Comment: @PeterBennett it seems you misunderstood me, as I've said the exact same thing as you - `if you reduced the voltage to correct the RMS to a value that the bulb can bear`; knowing only peak (or peak-to-peak) AC amplitude the device requires, he has to first divide it by the root-mean-square factor (sqrt(2) for regular sine AC); luckily, all the common mains devices are specified using RMS, so there is no calculation necessary - but since OP hasn't stated if he's concerned with mains devices mainly (sic!) or not, I think my remark stands in case he had a device that had peak V specified instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on the design of the power supply. A linear power supply typically starts out with a transformer across the input, for instance:

[image: A simple linear power supply, from Wikipedia]

Transformers only work on AC, so a device using this type of power supply wouldn't work at all on DC. (You'd just end up shorting out the input, and possibly burning out the transformer in the process.)

Switching power supplies are another matter. Many switching power supplies do use a bridge rectifier as the first component, so supplying them with DC at an equivalent voltage *might* work; they usually aren't dependent on the input being discontinuous. However, this is highly dependent on the exact design of the power supply, and I certainly wouldn't recommend it as a matter of course.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer**: No, most AC devices could not run off DC.

**In-depth answer**: There are very specific cases where this will work. If your input circuit is a diode rectifier followed by capacitors, after which everything in the system is expecting DC, then you should be able to feed DC into the circuit. You should even be able to ignore the polarity of the DC input.

If you have any transformers at all in the AC path, they will saturate, which will at best blow a fuse, and at worst damage something else in the path.

If there's a power factor corrector on the AC input, it's imaginable that it will work off DC, and it's imaginable that it won't. My bet would be that it won't.

Even in the best-case scenario, the losses in the diode pair being used will be a little more than twice the losses if you were running straight AC into them, because only one pair of diodes is all the current that was previously being seen by both pairs. (All this assumes single-phase. Three-phase is comparable, but with a 3x multiplier instead.) So unless the diodes have a large amount of overhead built into them, they're likely to overheat and fail.

Comment: To the list you could add more things like devices that use cockroft walton to generate their voltages.

Answer (score 4):

If the device uses a transformer to step down the voltage before rectifying it, it won't work on DC as the transformer does not work on DC.

If the device uses a CR dropper (some low power mains connected devices that do not need to be insulated from the mains), it won't work on DC as the capacitor blocks DC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmFFKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the device uses a voltage doubler (multiplier) then it won't work on DC since the voltage doubler needs AC to work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI57CQ.png)</sup>

Switching power supplies with active PFC may or may not work on DC depending on the specific PFC chip that is used.

Switching power supplies without a voltage doubler or active PFC may work on DC, but it would still depend on the power supply itself, but simple ones should work.

Answer (score 1):

Some AC power supply circuits have X-Cap discharge circuits which detect the absence of AC at the input and attempt to discharge the X-capacitor across the line.  Others have power factor correction circuitry or active bridge/bridgeless circuits which expect a rectified AC waveform at the input.  In those cases, feeding the supply with a DC voltage could cause a failure/fault or erratic operation.

If there's no circuitry that specifically requires the full-wave rectified signal then you should be OK to feed the path after the rectifier with DC.

Comment: where "AC device" = "AC power supply" yes. If the device involves a mains frequency transformer or induction motor ... different story.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Such a device wouldn't have a bridge rectifier as the first element in the path to begin with -- that's the premise of the OP's question.

Comment: @Dave Tweed : yes, it's possible to infer than from the question but it's not explicitly stated. Hence the caveat...

Answer (score 0):

AC devices like your washing machine, dishwasher, refrigerator and fans can't work off DC. Your air conditioning maybe can if the description includes the word "inverter", otherwise no.

These devices typically run on mains-connected AC motors. Wrong voltage or frequency, and they won't work.

Old-style printers also used to have mains-connected AC motors. Running on 50Hz AC power, they had a page speed 5/6 what was specified for 60Hz. Running on DC, assuming they didn't burn up, they'd have a page speed of zero.